# Local de download - Selenium Edge + Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Sou iniciante em programação, estou tentando criei um código no webdriver para fazer o download de um arquivo, mas procure pela internet sobre como alterar a pasta em que o download é colocado e o nome porém não achei.
Se puderem me indicar algum local em que possa ler sobre isso para tentar encontrar uma solução

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olha, eu uso assim, não me recordo onde eu encontrei para você pesquisar melhor.
Coloca esses comandos na internet e dá uma procurada melhor, mas isso funciona corretamente.

Você já vai abrir o navegador com a nova opção de pasta de download automático, então quando você fizer o seu download, automaticamente ele vai salvar no caminho definido.

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

salvar = 'seu caminho para salvamento'


    opts = EdgeOptions()
    opts.use_chromium = True
    opts.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": salvar})

    driver = Edge(options=opts)
    driver.maximize_window()
```